# Ignore commemts while parsing txt file C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++17

I have a large text file and I am parsing using string stream. Text file looks like this

```
#####
##bjhbv
nvf
vbhjbj
vfjbvjf
*bj
*bvjbv
.
.
.
.
+FILE
data I want to parse from here to 
.
.
.
.
-FILE 
till here
#shv again comments
.
.
```

How can I parse only between +FILE to -FILE? I can parse inside off it, but i just want to ignore above and below comments. Please help me how to ignore whie reading or parsing from .txt file. Any leads will be appreciated.,

Comment: Scan and discard tokens until you find `+FILE`, then scan and *don't* discard until you find `-FILE`.

Comment: Also you probably want to read the file line by line and parse the std::string line you read.

Comment: Can you guys tell me how to discard it! I should not want to delete it inside a file, I just want to ignore it. I prefer to start stream from +FILE only. Can you help me out please ?how to tokenize !

Comment: You stream from an input file to an output file, and so "discarding" means choosing not to duplicate it to the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the comments, you can discard above +FILE. you can use flag and condition method. Where use,

```cpp
while(some_condition)
{
 //ignore comments
 if(!std::find("#")) 
 {
   continue;
 }
 bool flag=false;
 if(!std::find("+FILE")) 
 {
   flag=true;
 }
 if(!std::find("-FILE"))
 {
   flag=false;
 }
if(flag)
 {
  ..
  ..
  ..
 }
}
```

You can also use enum and array index method if you have different string names. If you dont want to use std::find, if you are parsing through `getline`,then you can replace std::find to`line.at(0)`.

Comment: `std::istream::ignore` only allows you to skip input up to a single-character delimiter. You cannot specify a string.

Comment: I appreciate , but this is not the solution as the above @rici mentioned this skip input upto single character in line.

Comment: I appreciate , but this is not the solution as the above @rici mentioned this skip input upto single character in line.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```cpp
{
  ifstream f_in(input_file_name);
  ofstream f_out(output_file_name);

  string line;
  // discard up to "+FILE"
  while (getline(f_in, line) && line != "+FILE");
  // copy up to "-FILE"
  while (getline(f_in, line) && line != "-FILE") f_out << line << endl;
}
```

The `ifstream` and `ofstream` will close their respective files upon leaving scope, which is why I showed them within `{}`.

Comment: I appreciate this, actually this is my actual solution now. But I am searching for another approach, imagine in an hour you get 20GB+ file and need to write multiple files. Everytine I write the size of the space goes more again. Performance issue raises here.

Comment: Why does processing the file get slower? Are you processing the same information each time? Perhaps you need to remember your previous file position so that you can start the next scan where you left off.